# Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu skipped my document click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have write my own document click function `$(document).click(function(e) {` to trace click and hide my custom build menu. However, when I clicked on Bootstrap standard drop down menu, my document click function is being skipped from running.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

For better explanation, here is my sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/XwjE6/2/ As you can see if you clicked on "My Menu" and then click on "Settings", "My Menu" doesn't disappear.

How can I ensure my document click function is always listen click and execute code? So that I can get my menu to hide when user click on bootstrap menu. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without seeing more but I would guess that the menu click is being captured by an event listener and that listener is preventing the event from bubbling up to the document level. You could try adding your listener to the element itself and see if it works.

Comment: What I want is when standard bootstrap menu is clicked, my custom menu will automatically hide. Currently it can hide itself when I click on anywhere on the webpage, but it doesn't hide when I click on the standard menu which brings up drop down menu.

I tried to put console.log into $(document).click() and I found it doesn't run when bootstrap drop down menu is clicked.

Comment: Maybe this fiddle will help you understand what I'm trying to get at: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/NKQJU/

Notice that the button clicks do not fire the event attached to the document. That's because, in the button handler, I use `stopPropagation` to prevent the event from bubbling up from the element to the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. For better explanation, here is my sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/XwjE6/2/ As you can see if you clicked on "My Menu" and then click on "Settings", "My Menu" doesn't disappear. How can I solve that?

Comment: I don't know why. If you can't see the result in Chrome or IE, please try on Firefox.

Comment: I can't see any of the menu options in FF or Chrome.